# alert() entire multi-dimensional object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, alert, stringify

**My entire code example is below and on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rEhvt/.**

I'm trying to `alert()` my multi-dimensional JavaScript object. If I `alert()` a single property of the object - it works. For example:

```
alert(votes['77777'].stay);
```

However, if I try to `alert()` the entire object, then I either get a lot of `NULL`s or blanks. I tried the following:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(votes));//returns lots of NULLs

alert(votes.join('\n'));//returns lots of blanks
```

My intention is to eventually send the object to localStorage with

```
localStorage['votes']=JSON.stringify(votes);
```

and retrieve it with

```
retrievedVotes=JSON.parse(localStorage['votes'])
```

However, I want to first be able to see the object structure. This is my first attempts at understanding multi-dimensional objects with JavaScript, so any help you can offer is greatly appreciated! Below is all of my code, which is also on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rEhvt/.

```
//Movie #1
var movieID = 55555;
var stay = 'yes';

var votes = [];
votes[movieID]=[];
votes[movieID].stay = stay;

var scenes = 1;
votes[movieID].scenes = scenes; 

//Movie #2
var movieID = 77777;
var stay = 'no';

var votes = [];
votes[movieID]=[];
votes[movieID].stay = stay;

var scenes = 0;
votes[movieID].scenes = scenes; 

//Alert Single Item from votes
alert(votes['77777'].stay);

//Alert entire object
alert(JSON.stringify(votes));//returns NULLs

//Alert entire object
alert(votes.join('\n'));//returns lots of blanks
```

Comment: Use `console.log` or `console.dir` with your browser's dev tools, or firebug.

Comment: @canon Thanks! I thought I was using an object. How would I change my code to be an object instead of an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an object `{}` rather than an array `[]`... setting `votes[7777]` is going to reindex the array to accommodate 7,778 elements... with lots and lots of undefined elements (which `JSON.stringify()` will convert to `null`).

Plus, you're setting named properties on an array:

```
votes[movieID]=[];
votes[movieID].stay = stay;
```

Here's a functional sample using objects ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rEhvt/2/)):

```
var votes = {
    // Movie #1
    '55555': { 
        stay: 'yes',
        scenes: 1,
        outtakes: 0,
        enhanced: 0,
        teaser: 0
    },
    // Movie #2
    '77777': { 
        stay: 'no',
        scenes: 0,
        outtakes: 0,
        enhanced: 0,
        teaser: 0
    }   
};

console.log(votes[77777].stay);
console.log(votes);
```

and a 1-to-1 change in your provided code ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rEhvt/4/)):

```
//Movie #1
var movieID = 55555;
var stay = 'yes';

var votes = {}; // changed to {}
votes[movieID]= {}; // changed to {}
votes[movieID].stay = stay;

var scenes = 1;
votes[movieID].scenes = scenes; 
var outtakes = 0;
votes[movieID].outtakes = outtakes; 
var enhanced = 0;
votes[movieID].enhanced = enhanced; 
var teaser = 0;
votes[movieID].teaser = teaser; 

//Movie #2
var movieID = 77777;
var stay = 'no';

//var votes = []; removed
votes[movieID]= {};  // changed to {}
votes[movieID].stay = stay;

var scenes = 0;
votes[movieID].scenes = scenes; 
var outtakes = 0;
votes[movieID].outtakes = outtakes; 
var enhanced = 0;
votes[movieID].enhanced = enhanced; 
var teaser = 0;
votes[movieID].teaser = teaser; 

//Alert Single Item from votes
alert(votes['77777'].stay);

//Alert entire object/array
alert(JSON.stringify(votes));//returns NULLs​
```

Comment: Thanks for your initial comments, answer, and fiddle. I did not realize the difference between `[]` and `{}`.

Comment: I think your answer merged with xdazz's answer would be very nice. Your answer is comprehensive, but xdazz's answer simply shows how to fix the issue based on the code I provided.

Comment: Incorporated a slight modification to your original version... though, my first code sample is more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

```
var movieID = 55555;
votes[movieID]
```

This sets the 55555th index of votes to that movie! That's why you have tons of blanks. Same goes for 77777.

If you do

```
console.log(votes.length);
```

you'll see this result:

```
 77778
```

Another problem, you completely erase the array when you make the second movie by doing `var votes = [];`

You want to create objects instead of arrays. That's using curly braces `{ }` instead of `[ ]`

Comment: Thanks! In my rush to setup an example I accidentally put `var votes = [];` twice. Good catch! The rest of your answer is spot on and fixed the issue, now I just need to pick the most clear answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You may use `{}` instead of `[]` when you define `votes` variable.

When you define array and set a value by an index, then if there is no elements before it, it fills it by nulls. For example the code:

```
var arr = [];
arr[5]​ = 0;
alert(JSON.stringify(arr));​​​
```

will provide `[null,null,null,null,null,0]`.

Comment: Thanks! This was definitely the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `array`, but what you need is object.

Change

```
var votes = [];
votes[movieID]=[];
```

to

```
var votes = {};
votes[movieID]={};
```

and so on.

Comment: While everyone hit on what the issue was, I feel your answer is the most clear and concise based on the code I provided. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

#### `alert` is not a debug tool

You say you want "to first be able to see the object structure", so you should use proper developer tools. Your browser probably has those, press <kbd>F12</kbd>. If you use Firefox, install Firebug.

Then you can use commands like `console.log(votes)`, and the whole thing will be output to the developer console, and you can navigate it like a tree with the mouse.

If you really want to recursively `.toString()` every object and then `alert` it, it is possible, but I can't see any good reason to do that.

Comment: Thanks! I used `console.log(votes)` with Chrome's Developer tool and that worked very well. Thanks again!